# Wikipedia API. File not found Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to make a wikipedia search bar. The idea is to send a new AJAX request every time search input is changed. I'm using https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search_and_discovery as a guideline.

```
var search = $('#search');

search.keyup(function() {
  if (search.val() === '') {
    result.html('');
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: '//en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
    data: {
      action: 'query',
      list: 'search',
      format: 'json',
      srsearch: search.val()
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(response) {
      console.log("success!");
    }
  });
});
```

However, success function is not even triggered.
On any keypress the error I get is this ("d" pressed):

> jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4 GET file://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?>callback=jQuery21107844703783826772_1484403407494&action=query&list=search&srse>arch=d&format=json&_=1484403407495 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Thank you in advance for any help or guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're probably trying to do a AJAX request without a local server (opening your file directly in the browser).

First of all, your `url` options starts with `//en...` (without the protocol). It indicates that it'll construct your full url using the same protocol you're using. In this case: `file://`. That's because your browser is trying to reach `file://en.wikipedia.org/...`.

So, you can set your url to `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php` to make it work.

Just replace:

```
url: '//en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
```

with:

```
url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
```

Comment: You're right - changing to "https" fixed it and yes, I was running it locally. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're running it from a simple html file located in your filesystem, in other words not running it from a web server (even local).

Try calling the api with

```
url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'
```

or run the file from a web server (can be a local one).

Comment: You're right - changing to "https" fixed it and yes, I was running it locally. Thank you.